# Cyclical reference of classes in Python

Tags: python, class

I have a handful of classes, and each create a reference of the next one upon `__init__` initialization. However, I can't assign them through variables because you can't assign the first one to the last one because it doesn't exist yet:

```
class5= Class5(class1)  # UnresolvedReference here
class4= Class4(class5)
class3= Class3(class4)
class2 = Class2(class3)
class1= Class1(class2)

# There's also this, but it's the same thing

wiring = Class1(Class2(Class3(Class4(Class5(???)))))
```

How can that last one reference the first one? The classes need to be interchangeable, and any help would be welcome!

Comment: I'm curious what the scenario is where you need this cycle, because this looks like it may be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I remember facing a similar problem once (with two mutually-referential classes), and inventing a convoluted mimic class to solve it, when the simpler (and preferred) solution would be for them to just be a single class. In this case it looks like you'll just want to set these values outside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you want to do this:

```py
foo = Foo(car)
baz = Baz(foo)
car = Car(baz)
```

You can't do this. You could try to do a lazy construction though, by having the constructor call an `initialize()` method if the given param is non-None.

```py
foo = Foo(None)
baz = Baz(foo)
car = Car(baz)
foo.initialize(car)
```